# Can't grab certain a tags from a lazyloading site

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

Running my scraper i could see that it scrapes unnecessary links other than the links to each school what i require. I have created right xpaths, though. The site contains lazyloading method. Perhaps need to grab json response. I tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.boarding.org.au/find-a-school"
def LazyLoadWeb(address):
    try : 
        page = requests.get(address, timeout=30)
    except Exception: 
        print('timed out')
    else:
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"clearfix")]')
        for title in titles:
            links=title.xpath('.//a/@href')
            for link in links:
                print(link)

LazyLoadWeb(url)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get those links which are at the bottom with class 'clearfix' ?

Comment: Yes sir. Or alternatively the different school names if said explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about json response. This site uses Ajax to populate content. You need to make a post request and simply parse json from the response.

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.boarding.org.au/ajax-calls/GetSchoolsJson'
payload = {"state": 'null', "schoolType": 2, "orderMode": "ASC", "enableSchoolType": 'false', "loadAll": 'true'}
req = requests.post(url, json=payload)
data = req.json()
for i, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
    print(i, item['URL'])
# 1 /schools/details/4/Abbotsleigh
# ...
# 189 /schools/details/83/Yirara-College
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.